# How to Tag a branch Automatically in Azure DevOps using extension (Tag/Branch Git On Release)

Tags: azure-devops, branching-and-merging, tagging, azure-devops-extensions

With Azure DevOps release pipeline I'm planning to tag my brach Automatically by using the below extension which was created by Micheal Barry Tag\Branch Git on Release. See the below image:

[image]

I'm a bit wondering how to customize Tag name as `UAT_$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)`. Since this has limited documentation, this is how I try to add(See below)

How can I achieve this? Also, I'm more interested in how to fill these advanced options for this extension.

[image]

Comment: Check the extension's description: *Task for tagging or branching tfs git artifacts during a release with the release name.* .So the task's usage is related to the release name. It depends on how your release name format is defined when you want to determine which option to use. Static Tag Name or Regex. Hope my answer helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)` is only supported in [BuildNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#example) (Options=>Build Number Format) and [ReleaseNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-manage-the-names-for-new-releases) (Options=>Release Name format). So if you put `$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)` **directly** in `Static Tag Name`, the task can't evaluate its value.

Here're several directions to do what you want:

1. Use `$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)` as release name format.

[image]

Then use `UAT_$(Release.ReleaseName)` in `Static Tag Name` input.

[image]

The result:

[image]

PS: If you set build pipeline as release pipeline's artifact source, you can also use `$(Build.BuildNumber)/$(Build.DefinitionName)` in your Release name format.

2.If you prefer to use `Release-$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)` as release name format. Now since what you want is `UAT_xxx`, you need to use the `Regex` option:

[image]

Assuming your release name's instance is `Release-20200518.5`, now the tag would be `UAT_20200518.5` if you configure the task following my inputs above.

**In addition:**

When release name format is `$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)`, you releases would be:

[image]

You can choose to use the `Static Tag Name`, check #1 above.

And when the name format is `Release-$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)`, you releases would be:

[image]

You should use regex option in that third-party task, check #2 above. About what is Regex see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), also there's many documents/blogs online about Regex topic...

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong task in your pipeline. Would suggest using the git tag task, it works just fine to me and you can use your naming in the tag field
[Git Tag Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ATP.ATP-GitTag)

I find this extension much easier to setup and its satisfying our needs. So basically my git tag=assembly version. I am doing this every time we have a release on production environment(change assemblyInfo information and store that in Variable in the build definition). There are set of tasks on the marketplace to allow read from asemblyInfo and write to it. For the git tag task i just use the previously set Tag variable which basically is incremented by one every new release. You can check more in the pictures bellow

[image: 2]]

[image: 3]]

So i am actually just adding simple tag to mirror my assemblyVersion but in the tag message i am also adding my build informations that looks like this $(build.buildNumber)-$(Tag)

If you want to have a deeper look into azure devops predefined variables you can do that here [Use predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: To do this there are multiple extensions available but I selected this based on rating and no of installations which is a bit higher compared to others. but let me investigate on this one. would you mind adding more details of this extension here. with some screenshots.

Comment: @tech-gayan i edited my comment with more info about how i am using the task